# How to create a circular armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

let's say I wanted to rig and animate a torus. — is it possible to have a circular armature?

from what I can tell, this is not possible. so I thought maybe it's an idea to add a driver to the tail position of the last bone, that gets the head position of the first bone. however, this also doesn't seem to be an option.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHtyZ.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing, what you want to build will cast loop in parents (circular dependency), it doesn't allow. When Blender calculates bones coordinates, it moves from child through parents to root bone. And if you have loop in parents, blender can't find root bone

To avoid circular dependency you can bild rig like this:

[image]

[image]

This type of rig you can find in BlenRig, in lips rigging

[image]

Comment: Could you add a little description to your answer explaining how you achieved that result and how/why it works?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I've added a gif

Comment: The first one was enough, I meant an actual written text explanation detailing what you did and how. This is a good answer, and obviously you have put some effort into it, but as it stands this answer is non-searchable and not easily indexed, making it impossible to find through search, and hard to find for possible future users

Comment: Please expand on the answer, what seem obvious to you might not be to others. Use the text to answer the question and think of the images as supporting material, not the other way around

Comment: thanks, I figured it out studying the second gif. – still wondering though how you get the bones to snap to each other. I ended up using the `cursor to selected` and `selection to cursor` snap functions.

Comment: @kindoflike change snapping from snapping to increment (grid) to snapping to vertex.