# rigging - circular armature with rigid bones

Tags: rigging, armature, constraints

I'm trying to create a circular armature with rigid (non-stretching) elements having freely pivoting joints between them.  I've adapted the "lip rigging" solution presented by @Crantisz in reply to the question by @kindoflike in page "[How to create a circular armature?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81814/how-to-create-a-circular-armature)".  Seems like it will work well for me except that I want non-stretching bones, so I'm wondering which sort of constraint would be best suited other than "Stretch to".

I've tried some other listed constraints that seem like potential candidates, but they didn't work as I expected they might.  It's my first time even using armatures and still fairly new to Blender, so the answer may be in front of me but I don't see it.

Thanks!

Comment: The [Track To](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/tracking/track_to.html) constraint will point at the target without stretching.

Comment: True and thanks very much for the reply, but the problem is when I try that the joints come apart, which is effectively like the bones are stretching between joints.  I need the joints to stay connected although flexible to freely pivot.  I thought maybe to use Track To in combination with another constraint to keep the tracked bone ends from separating, but haven't found that complementary one yet.